# How to get blocks from which an adress has taken coins&

Tags: blocks

I need to undeerstand how to find out from which blocks come coins that are currently stored at somee adress.Will be pleased to hear any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You want the history of ether transfers from and to an account. That feature is not provided by regular clients like geth or parity.

You have to use a block indexer that will read the blockchain and store the result in a database.

If you were targeting ERC20 it is possible by tracking `Transfer` events. Unfortunately there's no events for ether transfers.